# Rails, Mongoid, using environment variable for database config throws NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy my rails application, which uses mongoid, to my remote production server.

In my `mongoid.yml` I have added this:

```
hosts:
    - <%= ENV['MONGOSERVER_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'] %>:27017
```

When I launch my capistrano, it throws me this error:

```
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for :"27017":Symbol
```

Does that adding underscores makes this error happen?

Comment: Had the same problem when running rake db:setup, due to the same error, in a Docker container. In my case, the docker-compose file was missing the env.variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the environment variable is nil, so it's just reading:

```
hosts:
    - :27017
```

It thinks that the host is a symbol, which is throwing it off.

Double check that your env var is set correctly and try it with quotes around the hosts:

```
hosts:
    - "<%= ENV['MONGOSERVER_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'] %>:27017"
```

Answer (score 1):

The line is being parsed as `- :27017`, which creates a `Symbol` rather than your URL string. This is probably due to your `ENV` variable not being defined; make sure you've defined it properly.

To answer the question "does adding underscores cause this error?": most likely no. Underscores are valid in environment variables.